# Why is this an error: static_cast<unsigned*>(&i)

Tags: c++, casting

By following the rule of thumb to prefer `static_cast` or `dynamic_cast` before everything else, I wrote the following program:

```
int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    unsigned *j = static_cast<unsigned*>(&i);
    return 0;
}
```

However, it does not even compile:

```
$ g++ --std=c++11 test5.cpp 
test5.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test5.cpp:4:44: error: invalid static_cast from type ‘int*’ to type ‘unsigned int*’
     unsigned *j = static_cast<unsigned*>(&i);
                                            ^
```

Why is this wrong? What is the correct cast for this situation?

Comment: You need `reinterpret_cast` for this.

Comment: It wouldn't have compiled with a `dynamic_cast`, either, so the entire premise is a bit deceptive.

Comment: @kennytm, that's what I am trying to avoid - `reinterpret_cast` and `(unsigned*)` are evil and I try to use them only as a last resort. I wasn't expecting to need them for such a  trivial task.

Comment: Don't program by using emotional memory. Instead, learn the rules, analyze the problem you need to solve, and then select an appropriate implementation for the solution. If you need to reinterpret an object as a different object, you need a reinterpret-cast (but you also need to understand what is and is not allowed).

Answer (score 8):

You can `static_cast` from an `int` to an `unsigned`, which performs the appropriate conversion. But what you have is a pointer; this pointer points to a region of memory that is to be interpreted as an `int`. Dereferencing the pointer yields the `int`'s value. [`static_cast` will not convert between pointers to unrelated types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast).

```
int i = 0;
int* ip = &i;
int j = *ip; // treat the region pointed to as an int
```

To treat the memory as `unsigned` under dereference, you need to reinterpret the memory; that's what `reinterpret_cast` does.

```
int i = 0;
int* ip = &i;
unsigned j = *reinterpret_cast<unsigned*>(ip); // treat the region pointed to as unsigned
```

You shouldn't do this, however. `reinterpret_cast` does exactly what it says: reinterprets the memory as a different type. If the bit pattern doesn't match what would be expected for that type, the result will differ from the conversion performed by `static_cast<unsigned>`. This can be the case on a system where signed integers are not represented using 2's complement, for instance.

The correct approach is to dereference the `int*` then `static_cast<unsigned>` the result of that:

```
int i = 0;
int* ip = &i;
unsigned j = static_cast<unsigned>(*ip); // treat the region pointed to as int
                                         // then convert the int to unsigned
```

To summarise: `static_cast` will perform the integer conversion, but it won't re-interpret a memory region as a different type. That's what `reinterpret_cast` is for.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to use:

```
unsigned *j = static_cast<unsigned*>(static_cast<void*>(&i));
```

this is what you can read [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) at point 5, or simply use:  [reinterpret_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast):

```
int i = 0;
unsigned *j = reinterpret_cast<unsigned*>(&i);
```

often instead of using cast-s programmers use unions as below:

```
union {
  int n;
  unsigned char bt[4];
} data;
data.n = i;
data.bt[3] = 0xff;
```

As it was said in comments, using union for casting is undefined behaviour - even if it is supported by most compilers : you can read more on this here: [Is using an union in place of a cast well defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6136010/is-using-an-union-in-place-of-a-cast-well-defined) and here [Is using an union in place of a cast well defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6136010/is-using-an-union-in-place-of-a-cast-well-defined)