# how to get an integer from a char array

Tags: c++, arrays, char, int

I have a char array that has '4''5'. But I want to convert those characters into actual integers so I subtract '0' from each index of the char array and store it into the same array. If I want to set an int called value to the 45 (the stuff inside the char array) How would I do it?

Comment: Could you please give an example input and an example output ?

Comment: There are plenty of existing questions about parsing numbers out of strings. Have you read any of them?

Comment: `int i; sscanf(charArray, "%d", &i);` `atoi(charArray))`

Comment: a) `scanf`, b) `atoi`, c) for positive integers in `int` range eg. `int sum = 0; for(int i = 0; i < strLen; i++) { sum *= 10; sum += chararr[i] - '0' }`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert char array to a int number in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10204471/convert-char-array-to-a-int-number-in-c)

Comment: Yeah same question. sorry and thanks!

Comment: If you end up choosing `atoi`, think again. If you get 0 back, you can't tell whether the conversion was successful. In C, `strtol` is a good replacement and in C++, `stoi` uses almost the same interface as `atoi`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6093414/convert-char-array-to-single-int & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633252/how-to-cast-an-array-of-char-into-a-single-integer-number

Answer (score 0):

atoi() converts string to integer. For example if you already have the char array and integer variable declared you can do:

```
   val = atoi(theCharArray);
```

[Duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6093414/convert-char-array-to-single-int)

Answer (score 0):

```html
int int_value;
int_value = atoi(your_char_array);
```

the `atoi()` Function is used to convert `string` to `int`.

more information about `atoi()` [Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/).